# Chrome Extension loses indexeddb when removed and readded

Tags: google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I decided to use indexeddb to store data for a chrome extension I wrote. I've noticed that if I remove the extension and readd it, the data is lost.

Is there a way to persist the database across re-installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps docs (which also applies to extensions) recommend using storage.sync to handle persistence across re-installations, but the quota is very limited: 102,400 bytes. And it's not the same thing as indexeddb so some data processing would need to be done.

If your data is bigger than that I think the only solution is to sync your data manually with a server-side component, either your own or some other cloud-based solution like Firebase:
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-06-power-your-chrome-extension-with-firebase.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out firebase. The data being stored will most likely exceed the storage limit as it is currently recording user notes and will also store additional information. 
I do use storage.sync for settings though.

Answer (score 1):

Indexeddb is temporary storage.  https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage

Browser may clear data anytime as necessary.

Until persistent data storage is available, possibly in combine with quota management api,  treat indexeddb data as temporary.

Comment: he's talking about chrome extensions and not chrome